# What to do when an Ubuntu auto-update breaks my system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome3

Yesterday I auto-updated software pushed via Ubuntu Software & Updates. Now my sound is broken and the application launcher thing freezes. I'm on Focal Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. GNOME 3.36.3.

How do I recover from this broken state? I can avoid the GUI locking up if I'm careful, and I can always `<C>+<A>+F3` to jump to the terminal to do work there.

Is there a way to rollback the updates? How do I even know what was installed?

Are there logs somewhere that need to be looked at?

What is the binary that runs the GUI and application launcher?

So many questions... Thank you!

---

`sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Do jump to the terminal, the run `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade `,  EDIT your post (above), type `<hr>` alone on a row and then copy and paste what apt update+upgrade printed below it (hmm... if not possible to copy; grab a camera and paste an image...).

Comment: That's done Hannu. I'm not sure what we would expect to see there?

Comment: I expected to see something broken. Seems I didn't read your question well enough. Check `apt --help` for a reinstall option. Run that on e.g. pulseaudio (other candidiates for broken sound: `dpkg --list | grep sound`) - harder to tell about GUI lockups; depends on your hardware and which drivers you use.

Comment: Ah, well I appreciate the assistance. Can you give any general advice about debugging gnome on Ubuntu? I'll need to hunt down error logs I suspect.

Comment: Latest news on this, apparently ~/.xsession-errors is the place to look. But since it isn't actually crashing, just misfunctioning, I don't see anything there.